# A Sql Query to search and replace specific prefixed strings?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, string, replace

Alright I have something like this(I messed it up...) -

```
Id Name                     City
1  XXX - New                Plano
2  XXX - XXX - New1         Dallas
3  XXX - XXX - XXX - New2   Sacramento
4  XXX - New3               Houston
5  XXX - XXX - New4         Austin
```

So, I want to replace all the occurrence with more that one `XXX` prefix to just 1. For e.g id 2 should have Name=`XXX - New2`. How would go about achieving this ? Even a query basically to check for a prefix and replace it with the name would work I think and then I can add the prefix again ? I mean set all the records just to say `New`,`New2`..so on...and then I can add XXX prefix to it ?

Comment: are all of the xxx's the same?

Comment: yeah xxx's are same..thx to evryone for rplies...srry for late reply..was caught up..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove all instances of 'XXX - ' with the string [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) function.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Name = Replace(Name, 'XXX - ', '')
```

Alternately, to keep a single instance you could use:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET Name = 'XXX - ' + Replace(Name, 'XXX - ', '')
WHERE CHARINDEX('XXX - ', Name) > 0
```

Comment: Doesn't OP want to keep one instance though?

Comment: @gbn, @nathan gonzalez: They do say that even replacing the records with just the Name so they could add a single 'XXX - ' back on would be okay. I'll update my answer to keep one instance though

Comment: 1. your solution *was* incomplete until update: it does not provide an end to end solution to fix OPs data problem. 2. It updates every row when only a few may be broken = one big transaction possibly.

Comment: @gbn: 1. As I had noted, it did only solve removing the prefixes. The user would have had to re-add the prefixes. I never claimed it would do otherwise.  2. I've updated again to replace with a single instance and to only modify records that contain the starting prefix already. Thanks for pointing the omission out.

Answer (score 2):

You want to strip out occurrences 2 to n of the string "`XXX -` ". 
This assume the data at the end needs preserved:

```
SELECT 'Starting' --also sets @@ROWCOUNT
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
    UPDATE
       Bollixedtable
    SET
       name = STUFF (name, 7, 6, '')
    WHERE
       SUBSTRING (name, 7, 6) = 'XXX - '
```

Otherwise, this removes the XXX and resets your data, based on the `XXX - New(id-1)` pattern with no filter if you want to start again

```
    UPDATE
       Bollixedtable
    SET
       name = 'XXX - New' + CAST(id-1 AS varchar)
```

Edit: updated for clarity

Comment: wouldn't this remove all instances, not all but one?

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: No, it only looks as the 2nd occurrence on each iteration

Comment: ah, i see that now...  gotta pay more attention to the start on the substring i like it.  a little cleaner than mine. +1\

Comment: Just for thoroughness, this also assumes that the original data does not need to be preserved...i.e. you want to update the data in the table, and not just create a view on top of it or select data out of it with the extra 'XXX - ' occurences striped out.

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: I think you've misunderstood.. I've edited to make it clear

Comment: @gbn: What I was clarifying is that this solution actually changes data in the table (UPDATE BOLLIXEDTABLE), rather than simply selecting data out of the table and formating it to the desired output.

Comment: @Richard, i thought it was understood that the op has screwed up his table and was attempting to fix it.  selects don't really fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Table
Set Name = Replace(
                Replace(
                    Replace( Name, ' - XXX - ', ' - ')
                    , ' - XXX - ', ' - ')
                , ' - XXX - ', ' - ')
```

This solution should handle most variants. For example, it will handle all the way out to:

`XXX - XXX - XXX - XXX - XXX - XXX - XXX - XXX - New2`.

If you need to handle it out further, you can simply add another Replace call.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on the data and how uniform it is. If all your data falls into the formats that you have in your question, then the simplest would be:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    'XXX - ' + SUBSTRING(NAME, CHARINDEX('NEW',NAME),LEN(Name)-CHARINDEX('NEW',NAME)) AS Name,
    CITY
FROM
    FOO
```

Otherwise, it could get a lot more complicated. Tell us more about the uniformity of your data and what the format's you will run into are, i.e. could you have `XXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXX - ad infintum`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you just wanted to strip the string of all the parts before the last "`-`" and then add a prefix again, you can use this:

```
UPDATE tblWhatever
SET Name = 'NewPrefix - ' + RIGHT(Name, CHARINDEX(' - ',REVERSE(Name))-1)
```

This just basically, searches for the last occurrence of "`-`" and then uses the `right()` function to get the last part of the string. It then appends the prefix onto that.

This is essentially what you described in the last part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable 
set name = rtrim(ltrim(replace(name, 'XXX - XXX', 'XXX - '))) 

update myTable 
set name = rtrim(ltrim(substring(name, charindex(name, '-'), len(name)))) 
where name like '%-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @loop bit
set @loop = 1

while @loop
begin
  update table
  set name = right(name,len(name)-6)
  where left(name,12) = 'xxx - xxx - '

  set @loop = @@rowcount
end
```